# Graphical issues in vim

Tags: vim

Not sure if this is the best place to ask this but does anyone know why I'm seeing those purple-ish bars in my vim?

My vimrc http://dpaste.com/698999/

Also, I'm using Lion OSX

[image]

Comment: Youre not overriding (manually setting) your `$TERM` variable are you? That can cause this behavior since it'll try to use the wrong terminal settings.

Comment: @Patrick, very interesting, as I override my $TERM to xterm-256color (by default I think it is xterm) for the sake of implementing Solarized via .Xresources. I will see if the same happens without the override.

Answer (score 1):

I would try different color schemes, e.g.

```
:colorscheme default
```

I found that some color schemes have this problem with some terminals. Perhaps the scheme wants 256 color support and your terminal isn't capable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this happens but I experience it on vim in xterm with the solarized colour scheme. To fix it, I suspend vim (ctrl-z), reset the terminal (the reset command) and resume vim (fg).

So possibly the terminal has entered a weird state not anticipated by vim.

This happens more when editing LaTeX than when editing C++ or bash scripts. It seems to be tied to certain keystrokes.

Comment: You can also force vim to clear-and-redraw with Ctrl+L or `:redraw!`.

Comment: That's interesting, considering I have bound ctrl-L to execute pdflatex. Might there be any connection?

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you think those things might be related? It seems like coincidence. People often bind keys over default bindings because they weren't using the defaults.

Comment: I don't know, I was just wondering, not trying to point out anything concrete. It probably is coincidence. And indeed, I wasn't using the default binding.